# Exit bitcoind gracefully in a bash script

Tags: bitcoind, bash

I'm writing a bash script for some Bitcoin / Lightning experiments. I want to start `bitcoind` in the background (and also LN instances, but they are not the focus of this question). I want the script to shutdown `bitcoind` gracefully and exit on `Ctrl+C`. This is my attempt to implement this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Starting bitcoind in the background..."
bitcoind &
sleep 5
echo "bitcoind started."
BITCOIND_PID=$!
echo $BITCOIND_PID

cleanup() {
    echo 'cleaning up'
    pkill $BITCOIND_PID
    exit
}

trap "cleanup" INT

# Run the script until we stop it
wait
```

This script produces the following output:

```
<some bitcoind output>
bitcoind started.
18574
2019-09-17T14:12:20Z Adding fixed seed nodes as DNS doesn't seem to be available.
^C2019-09-17T14:14:07Z tor: Thread interrupt
cleaning up
2019-09-17T14:14:07Z opencon thread exit
2019-09-17T14:14:07Z torcontrol thread exit
2019-09-17T14:14:07Z addcon thread exit
2019-09-17T14:14:07Z Shutdown: In progress...
2019-09-17T14:14:07Z net thread exit
sergei:~$ 2019-09-17T14:14:07Z msghand thread exit
2019-09-17T14:14:07Z scheduler thread interrupt
2019-09-17T14:14:07Z Dumped mempool: 2e-06s to copy, 0.004053s to dump
2019-09-17T14:14:07Z [default wallet] Releasing wallet
2019-09-17T14:14:07Z Shutdown: done
```

Then I have to press `Ctrl+C` once again to exit the script.

How do I make the script shutdown `bitcoind` first and then exit automatically?

Related: [How to use Ctrl+C to kill all background processes started in a Bash script?](https://superuser.com/questions/1118204/how-to-use-ctrlc-to-kill-all-background-processes-started-in-a-bash-script), [Best way to kill processes created by bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350676/best-way-to-kill-processes-created-by-bash-script/350680#350680).

Answer (score 2):

Is bitcoin-cli available? If so, `bitcoin-cli stop` instead of `pkill $BITCOIND_PID`.

My own preference is to add `sleep 2` following a stop, as I've experienced issues immediately restarting the stopped daemon where it behaves like a child thread hasn't finished cleaning up before the parent exits. That may not be what's happening - I've not investigated that behaviour.

Comment: I replaced 'pkill $BITCOIND_PID` with `bitcoin-cli stop; sleep 2`. Now I have: ```^C2019-09-18T09:23:50Z tor: Thread interrupt
2019-09-18T09:23:50Z Shutdown: In progress...
cleaning up
<...>
error: Could not connect to the server 127.0.0.1:18443
<...>
2019-09-18T09:23:50Z Shutdown: done``` which probably means the stop signal is sent to bitcoind two times: "directly" and through my trap. So when `bitcoin-cli` is called, `bitcoind` is already stopped. How can I prevent `bitcoind` from exiting before I call `bitcoin-cli stop`?

Comment: I see the same behaviour here, with differences I attribute to testing on 0.13.2. It might not be the stop signal being sent twice - it could be an attempt to discern if the initial shutdown was successful.